# Partial view. Error in ASP with Oracle: ORA-00933 SQL command not properly ended

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, entity-framework

I have a web site in ASP, using NET Framework 4.5, Entity Framework 6.1.3, connected to a Oracle Database 11, running on IIS 10 and Windows Server 2019.

The main view host a dynamic partial view (that is indicated by an ID). I have this problem where after a few days, I get the error **Server Error in '/' Application**, ***ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended***.

Then when I try debugging the project in Visual Studio, I don't get the error, and the only solution is to replace the files of the site and restart it. And then, some days later, I get the same error (and somethimes in anothers partial views).

Anyone had this problem? Or have an idea on what is it causing it?

When the exception is thrown (in the site on the IIS), also indicates the line:

```
Entidades.CONTROL_ACCESO controlAcceso = db.CONTROL_ACCESO.Find(idControlAcceso);
```

Comment: I would use from  cmd.exe >Netstat -a which give the list of open UDP/TCP connection and the status.  I suspect the connection closed.  Using a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler you can check why the connection closed.  A closed is indicated by a [FIN].  So three things can happen 1) Client closes the connection 2) Server Closes the connection 3)  Server shuts down without closing the connection.  When server restarts the connection is not automatically reestablished.

Comment: Do those statements, by any chance, end with a terminator (like semi-colon or slash)? If so, try to remove them and see what happens.

Comment: Also, please check [this post](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) Its about HttpClient, but it seems, it is an overall 'connection class' problem. Another hint (wont help you now): [dump/log your generated sql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/logging-and-interception?redirectedfrom=MSDN) when it runs into an exception.